# Is a mutex necessary when waiting on a condition variable? [w/ example code]

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

In my program I must first initialize the worker threads, and then initialize the thread resources. Once the resource is initialized, it is consumed by the threads AND the threads cannot start until the resource has been initialized. I want to control access to the resource queue AND maintain a count of resources. After the resources are consumed, I want to kill the threads. Assume the mutexes are intialized properly.
In order to tackle this I have tried the following:

```
pthread_mutex_t resource_mutex;
pthread_mutex_t unit_mutex;
pthread_cond_t  resource_consumed;
pthread_cond_t  start_consuming;
```

main.c

```
// 1) Initialize threads
...
// 2) Initialize resources
...
// global extern variable of type int
resource_units = 10;
pthread_cond_broadcast(&start_consuming, &resource_mutex);

pthread_mutex_lock(&unit_mutex);
pthread_cond_wait(&resource_consumed, &unit_mutex);
// kill or join threads
...
pthread_mutex_unlock(&unit_mutex);
return;
```

thread.c

```
pthread_cond_wait(&start_consuming, &resource_mutex);
for( ; ; ) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&resource_mutex);
    // consume resource unit
    ...
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&resource_mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&unit_mutex);
    resource_units --;
    if (resource_units == 0)
        pthread_cond_signal(&resource_consumed);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&unit_mutex);
}
```

However, when I start this program, it hangs on the first mutex_lock. I think I might be misunderstanding the usage of condition variables, and would like to understand how to achieve my desired control over synchronization in a MT program.

Comment: Read the manual: "*The pthread_cond_timedwait() and pthread_cond_wait() functions shall block on a condition variable. They shall be called with mutex locked by the calling thread or undefined behavior results.*"

Comment: Yes but "Assume the mutexes are intialized properly". I mean I understand your issue though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a mutex is required to use a POSIX condition variable correctly.  The condition variable is used to signal that some shared state **may** have changed, and the mutex involved protects that shared state from concurrent access.

Your thread startup condition isn't correctly checking any shared state - it's trying to just wait on a condition variable alone, which is not correct.  You could fix this by initialising `resource_units` to `-1`, then waiting for it to become non-negative at the start of the worked threads.  `resource_units` is protected by `unit_mutex`, so this is the correct mutex to lock and pass to `pthread_cond_wait()` here:

(thread.c)

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&unit_mutex);
while (resource_units < 0)
    pthread_cond_wait(&start_consuming, &unit_mutex);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&unit_mutex);
```

The corresponding code in `main.c` should first initialise the resources, then set `resource_units` and signal `start_consuming`.  It must lock `unit_mutex` around the update to `resource_units`:

(main.c)

```
// 1) Initialize threads
...
// 2) Initialize resources
...
// global extern variable of type int initialised to -1
pthread_mutex_lock(&unit_mutex);
resource_units = 10;
pthread_cond_broadcast(&start_consuming);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&unit_mutex);
```

(Note that you can't initialise `resource_units` to `0` and wait for it to become non-zero, because there is a possibility that the resources will be initialised and then all consumed by other worker threads before one worker gets the mutex - so it will end up stuck there forever.  `-1` works because after resource initialisation, `resource_units` will never get back to that value again.)

The code at the end of `thread.c` that signals `resource_consumed` when `resource_units` reaches zero is correct.  The corresponding code in `main.c` needs to examine the shared state (`resource_units`).  It cannot keep `unit_mutex` locked while it tries to join the threads, because a thread may have that mutex locked so you will have a deadlock:

(main.c)

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&unit_mutex);
while (resource_units > 0)
    pthread_cond_wait(&resource_consumed, &unit_mutex);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&unit_mutex);
// join threads
...
```

You should allow the threads to exit on their own and join them - killing threads is much harder to reason about than having them exit in a defined fashion.  In this case, it appears they should exit when `resource_units` reaches zero.  They should also only take a resource *after* decrementing `resource_units` (to ensure that multiple threads don't try to take the last resource).  `unit_mutex` must be held while examining `resource_units`, so the complete `thread.c` would look like:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&unit_mutex);
while (resource_units < 0)
    pthread_cond_wait(&start_consuming, &unit_mutex);

/* unit_mutex still held */
while (resource_units > 0)
{
    /* decrement resource_units because we will consume a resource */
    resource_units--;
    if (resource_units == 0)
        pthread_cond_signal(&resource_consumed);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&unit_mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&resource_mutex);
        // consume resource unit
        ...
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&resource_mutex);

    /* unit_mutex must be held at start of loop */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&unit_mutex);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&unit_mutex);
```

Now you probably don't need `resource_mutex` at all - if you make the queue of resources protected by `unit_mutex` instead, you can dequeue a resource after decrementing `resource_units` and before unlocking `unit_mutex`.

Comment: What's the need for the `resource_consumed` CV?  Its use seems to be to delay the main thread attempting to join the others, but why not just go straight to `pthread_join`, instead?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: In this case that's definitely possible (and similarly the `start_consuming` CV could be replaced by a barrier) but I felt that was a bit too much of a departure from the question.